# How to estimate join probability?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**Problem:**
a fair die is rolled at the same time as a fair coin is tossed. Let A be the number on the upper surface of the die and let B describe the outcome of the coin toss, where B is equal to 1 if the result is “head” and it is equal to 0 if the result if “tail”. The random variables X and Y are given by X = A + B and Y = A − B, respectively. **Calculate P(X,Y)**?

**Answer:**
since both events A and B are independent,  P(A=a,B=b) can be found; P(A=a,B=b) = 1/6*1/2 = 1/12. With the provided information, P(X) and P(Y) can also be calculated. I am not sure how to calculate P(X,Y)? Any help will be appreciated?

```
X = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} -> pX(x) = {1/12, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/12}


Y = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6} -> pY(y) = {1/12, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/12}
```

Comment: Well, what are the possible values of $X,Y$?  What is the probability that, say, $(X,Y)=(1,1)$?

Comment: If you know $X$ and $Y$ you can use that to find $A$ and $B$.  Notice that $A = \dfrac{X+Y}{2}$ and $B=\dfrac{X-Y}{2}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JMoravitz you mean $p(a_i)p(b_i) = P(\frac{x_i+y_i}{2})P(\frac{x_i-y_i}{2})$ ?

Comment: Your notation is lacking, but yes I do mean to imply that $P(X=x,Y=y)=P(A=\frac{x+y}{2},B=\frac{x-y}{2})=P(A=\frac{x+y}{2})P(B=\frac{x-y}{2})$

Comment: @JMoravitz could you explain why $P(X=x, Y=y) = P(A=a, B=b)$ this is true?

Comment: Because $X+Y=(A+B)+(A-B)=2A$ and so on... again going back to my first comment, knowing $X$ and $Y$ uniquely determines the values of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I didn't get it (: anyway thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to get to $P(X = x, Y = y)$ directly from $P(X = x)$ and $P(Y = y)$. It is simpler to get there from $P(A = a, B = b)$.

Take an example,

$P(X = 1) = \frac{1}{12}$, $P(Y = 1) = \frac{1}{6}$.

There is only one possible way for $X = 1$ which is die shows $1$ and you get a tail on the coin. So the probability of $\frac{1}{12}$.

But when it comes to $P(Y = 1)$, you have two possible ways: $1$ on the die and tail on the coin OR $2$ on the die and head on the coin. So the probability of $\frac{1}{6}$.

Now when it comes to finding $P(X = 1, Y = 1)$, please note that you are looking for probability where the sum and difference are both $1$ which is only possible if die showed $1$ and you got a tail on the coin.

So to find $P(X = 1, Y = 1)$, we focus on $1$ on the die and tail on the coin which is nothing but $P(A = 1, B = 0) = \frac{1}{12}$.

If $A = 1, B = 1$, given $X = A + B, Y = A - B \implies A = \frac{X + Y}{2} = 1, B = \frac{X - Y}{2} = 0$ and that is why we found $P(A = 1, B = 0)$.

Valid combinations of X, Y are

i) $\{1, 1\}, \{2, 2\}, \{3, 3\}, \{4, 4\}, \{5, 5\}, \{6, 6\}$ that correspond to $A = a, B = 0$.

ii) $\{7, 5\}, \{6, 4\}, \{5, 3\}, \{4, 2\}, \{3, 1\}, \{2, 0\}$ that correspond to $A = a, B = 1$.

All of the above combinations will have probability of $\frac{1}{12}$. Rest of them will have probability of zero. For example , $P(X = 1, Y = 0) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your nice explanation :)

Comment: @GPrathap you are welcome.